# How to Integrate Button component with Form component?

Tags: uicomponent, xml, adminform, action

I try to add my custom button to the form, not to the header of the form, but after some fields inside the fieldset, I found some examples here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-button.html like this

```
<form>
...
<fieldset>
    ...
    <button name="custom_button">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="buttonClasses" xsi:type="string">custom-button-class</item>
                <item name="actions" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="targetName" xsi:type="string">TARGET_NAME</item>
                        <item name="actionName" xsi:type="string">ACTION_NAME</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <displayAsLink>false</displayAsLink>
            <title translate="true">Custom Button</title>
        </settings>
    </button>
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

but in this code I can choose my own controller actin, just choose between some of predefined. Actually, I need to add two buttons, which will send form data(submit form) to different actions. It must work like a 'save' action if I chose

```
<item name="actionName" xsi:type="string">save</item>
```

Does anyone know, hot to do it? Maybe I can define my own action and set it here? Thank you a lot.
It looks like this [image]

Comment: do you want to add a custom button to the admin grid list?

Comment: no, i want to add my buttons to custom form and this buttons must submit form data to two different controllers. Like this https://i.imgur.com/IC0PytG.png

Answer (score 0):

**Step-1:** Create Generic.php at app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Block/Adminhtml/Edit/Button

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context;
use Magento\Cms\Api\PageRepositoryInterface;

class Generic
{
    protected $context;
    protected $pageRepository;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageRepositoryInterface $pageRepository
    ) {
        $this->context = $context;
        $this->pageRepository = $pageRepository;
    }

    public function getUrl($route = '', $params = [])
    {
        return $this->context->getUrlBuilder()->getUrl($route, $params);
    }
}
```

**Step-2:** Create Back.php at app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Block/Adminhtml/Edit/Button

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;

class Back extends Generic implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        return [
            'label' => __('Back'),
            'on_click' => sprintf("location.href = '%s';", $this->getBackUrl()),
            'class' => 'back',
            'sort_order' => 10,
        ];
    }

    public function getBackUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/');
    }
}
```

**Step-3:** Create Reset.php at app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Block/Adminhtml/Edit/Button

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;

class Reset implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        return [
            'label' => __('Reset'),
            'class' => 'reset',
            'on_click' => 'location.reload();',
            'sort_order' => 30,
        ];
    }
}
```

**Step-4:** Create Delete.php at app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Block/Adminhtml/Edit/Buttons

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;

class Delete extends Generic implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
    protected $context;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context
    ) {
        $this->context = $context;
    }

    public function getButtonData()
    {
        $data = [];
        $id = $this->context->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        if ($id) {
            $data = [
                'label' => __('Delete'),
                'class' => 'delete',
                'on_click' => 'deleteConfirm(\'' . __(
                    'Are you sure you want to delete this?'
                ) . '\', \'' . $this->getDeleteUrl() . '\')',
                'sort_order' => 20,
            ];
        }
        return $data;
    }

    public function getDeleteUrl()
    {
        $id = $this->context->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/delete', ['id' => $id]);
    }
}
```

**Step-5:** Create Save.php at app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Block/Adminhtml/Edit/Button

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Control\Container;

class Save extends Generic implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        return [
            'label' => __('Save'),
            'class' => 'save primary',
            'data_attribute' => [
                'mage-init' => [
                    'buttonAdapter' => [
                        'actions' => [
                            [
                                'targetName' => 'your_form_ui_component_name.your_form_ui_component_name',
                                'actionName' => 'save',
                                'params' => [
                                    false,
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

}
```

**Step-6:** In your Form Ui-Component file at app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/ui_component add below code:

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        ............................................................................................................
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="back" xsi:type="string">VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button\Back</item>
            <item name="delete" xsi:type="string">VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button\Delete</item>
            <item name="reset" xsi:type="string">VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button\Reset</item>
            <item name="save" xsi:type="string">VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button\Save</item>
        </item>
        ............................................................................................................
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="your_form_data_source_name">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">your_form_data_source_name</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="*/*/save"/>
              </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    ................................................................................................................
</form>
```

After adding above files run below command:

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento c:c
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but it is not what i whanted, i added image to post to show, what exactly i mean.